# How to count records in a table and get the value into an Activity?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I tried to use this code in my DBHandler class

```
public int getPointsCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_STUDENTS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();
        return cursor.getCount();
    }
```

and I used this call in a button in main Activity, but it causes my app to crash when I click the Button

```
callButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
             int cn =  countStudents();
                studentNumberText.setText(cn);
            }
        });

public int countStudents (){
        DBHandler dbHandler = new DBHandler(this, null, null, 1);
        int c = dbHandler.getPointsCount();
        return c;
    }
```

Comment: Select count(*) from tablename.http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp

Comment: `it causes app crash` = post your logcat

Answer (score 0):

Get the table count by calling this method

```
public int gettablecount(){
    Cursor mCount= db.rawQuery("select count(*) from TABLENAME ", null);
    mCount.moveToFirst();
    int count= mCount.getInt(0);
    mCount.close();
    return  count;
}
```

Comment: You can also select all the rows and get the cursor count. This doesn't answer why the app crashes, though

Comment: please Post your Log if app get crash

Comment: I didn't post the question. Once you have enough reputation, you can comment on the question

Comment: the answer seems right to get rows count but i think my problem is the way of calling the countStudents () from main activity.. can any one prepare full example ?

Comment: please referlink http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/754766/this-is-my-code-for-loginDataBaseAdapter-and-DataB   LoginDataBaseAdapter.class declare method gettablecount(), and initialize LoginDataBaseAdapter on MainActivity.class                                                                                                               (LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter = new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);                                                          
int tablecount=loginDataBaseAdapter.gettablecount();)